# MSC of Point Set Topology (Mathematical Subject Classification)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, set-theory

In which lower level class belongs Point Set Topology?
[1]: https://zbmath.org/static/msc2020.pdf

Is it part of MSC03E-Set-theory, or part of MSC-54-General-topology?

Do you have a collection of relating keywords to MSC-classes?

It helps to see the connections.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by "lower class" you mean elementary and expository papers/textbooks, nearly all of these are probably included in one of the following classifications: 54-00 and 54-01 and 54-02 and 54-03. However, many items with these classifications will not be as elementary as you might be looking for, but these are the classifications under which you'll find nearly all of the elementary items.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are doing. I assume by lower level you really mean high level, or general, or 2-digit class. In that case, 54 is general topology, 26 is real functions, 03 is mathematical logic and foundations. "Point-set topology" most likely refers to the stuff in 54, or to the theory of Baire functions, as in 26A21, or to descriptive set theory, as in 03E15. That said, the latter two are also considered in 54 (perhaps with different emphasis).

MathSciNet allows you to search for reviews containing specific words or sentences. If you have access to the database, this may help you identify the appropriate classes you are interested in.